# Create empty Dataframe with same dimensions as another?

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched a bit, but can not find a good answer. I want to create an empty dataframe with same dimensions as another dataframe so I can add new columns. Today I create an empty dataframe filled with zeroes, and then I delete the zero column. I hope there is a better way, but can not find the answer. Can someone help me?

I do like this today and it works, but it is very ugly.

```
df_copy = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.zeros(len(df_original.index))) 
df_copy = df_copy.drop([0],axis=1)
```

And now I can add new columns as I process data. So basically I want an empty dataframe with same dimensions as another dataframe.

```
df_copy["price"] = pricesList
df_copy["size"] = sizesList
```

EDIT: Another closely related question: how do I create an empty Dataframe with dimensions mxn? I have got the answer below how to create an empty dataframe with dimensions 1xn, which is by setting the index. But how do I create an empty nxm dataframe filled with zeroes? The reason I am asking, is because I suspect(?) it is faster to create a zero filled dataframe, and then replace each element as needed. The alternative is to create an empty dataframe with dimensions 1xn and then add columns as needed - which I am told is slow. So it might be faster to create an empty dataframe with nxm dimensions and then replace elements as needed (by copying a list to each column). Say a column has 100 rows, and I create a sublist with 25 rows, so I just copy this list to the correct subcolumn, and repeat. This is faster than adding a new column?

Comment: You don't need to fill it with zeros, it can just be empty to start with: ``pd.DataFrame(index=df_original.index)``

Comment: in general creating an empty frame, then filling it column by column is not very efficient; use a dict/list instead, or create sub-frames and concat them

Comment: @Jeff can you give some sample code on both approaches? Just a few lines. Would be much appreciated (also good for future references)

Comment: lots of examples in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: How do I select one answer, as the correct answer? I have pressed orange arrow up so it is says "2" now, is it correct? And I have edited my question and added a closely related follow up question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Creating an empty dataframe with the same index and columns as another dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df_copy = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df_original)
```

Comment: Not sure this works anymore. When I did it, instead of being empty the data frame is returning all items as NaN. It's not empty, being entirely full of NaN.

Comment: You can add `.dropna()` to the expression to empty out all the NaN entries.

Comment: If you want just the same columns but no rows with nan's, you can use `df_copy = pd.DataFrame().reindex(columns=df_original.columns)`

Comment: This approach creates a DataFrame full of NaNs, not a DataFrame with zero rows.

Answer (score 48):

For anyone coming to this page looking to create a dataframe of same columns, same dtypes, and no rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_copy = df_original.iloc[:0,:].copy()
```

Answer (score 16):

```
import pandas as pd 
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(index=df_original.index,columns=df_original.columns)
```

Comment: This creates a dataframe full of NaNs

Comment: Like @crypdick mentioned, it creates a dataframe with the exact number of rows (& columns ofcourse). Hence, the `NaNs` being auto-populated. Work around would be emptying the dataframe via `df_copy = df_copy[0:0]` after. However, check @gwelter comment for a more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 4):

@GaspareBonventre's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28141911/517835) can be slow, because of [an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24368) with the Pandas DataFrame constructor. I find it much faster to do

```
import numpy as np
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(df_original.shape))
df_copy.index = df_original.index
df_copy.columns = df_original.columns
```

Answer (score 2):

This one just keeps `columns` for you :)

```py
empty_df = df.iloc[:0]
```